# Emission of light by an electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, photon-emission

I always have a doubt when someone says that light is emitted by only certain transitions of electron but not by all of them. If an electron jumps from a higher energy orbit to a low energy orbit, is the energy difference released only in the form of a photon packet or does it release in any other forms of energy? Now, I say that a material can emit light in so and so wavelength, does it mean that the object is transparent to those wavelengths and other wavelengths are just absorbed to generate heat?

Comment: Hi, you could cite your source : **always have a doubt when someone says that light is emitted by only certain transitions of electron but not by all of them.** thanks

Comment: There, I was talking about a general convention that only some of the transitions of the electron emit light and others do not. Which is perhaps the reason why led has a sharper wavelength of light compared to a bulb.

Comment: "Transitions" of electrons apply to atomic energy levels. But in a sense something similar happens in LEDs. Incandescent bulbs on the other hand make use of black-body radiation, not transitions.

Comment: Here I am having a doubt regarding the emission of light by atoms. Can you please explain how only certain transitions give light and others are converted into heat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The energy freed by the transition from a higher to a lower energy state can be released by various other mechanisms (which observe conservation laws) in addition to the emission of a photon. An example is the Auger effect, where the energy is released by the kinetic energy of another emitted electron. In solids (semiconductors), the transition energy is often released by a photon plus a phonon which is necessary for momentum conservation.

Postscript: Upon suggestion of @CountTo10 I add some links I have found.
Here a lecture on radiative transitions mentioning also some non-radiative ones in gases https://legacy.wlu.ca/documents/37121/NotesCh4.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auger_effect

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/1749062.pdf

Comment: +1 if there was ever  an answer to be expanded on, this is the one. How many are told ...    photon in  followed by photon out. E and p are conserved and **that's it.** Even a few links to other processes would be  very helpful.